# PowerShell DownloadFile() not working for Nexus artifact download

Tags: powershell, webclient

I am trying to download the latest artifact from a Nexus repository. If I give the exact zip file name, it is working fine. When I try to download using a generic URL (REST URI) its giving me 401 Unauthorized. I have tried `Invoke-WebRequest`, `WebClient` and `Invoke-RestMethod` as well.

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$URL = "http://nexusrepo/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=my-snapshot&g=my.group.id&a=my.artifact.id&v=1.10.0-SNAPSHOT&c=win32.win32.x86_64&p=zip"
$username = "nexus"
$password = "nexus"
$auth = $username + ":" + $password
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$Encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($auth)
$EncodedPassword = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Encoded)
$wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate")
$wc.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + $EncodedPassword)
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $false
$wc.DownloadFile($URL, "MyApp.zip")
```

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server
returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
At C:\temp\NexusDownloadTest\Nexus-Download.ps1:39 char:1
+ $weburl = $wc.DownloadString($URL)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Do the logs on the Nexus server show something?

Comment: I don't have access to Nexus server's logs.

Comment: Still looking for answer. The header information is getting lost once its been redirected. Any idea how we can again set the Header information in the redirected URL in PowerShell? Appreciate it if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

As an workaround, I went back to Invoke-WebRequest and first got the redirected URL by using MaximumRedirection 0 and then submitted that URL as a request. The below code works.

```
$URL = "http://nexusrepo/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=my-snapshot&g=my.group.id&a=my.artifact.id&v=1.10.0-SNAPSHOT&c=win32.win32.x86_64&p=zip"
$username = "nexus"
$password = "nexus"
$auth=$username+":"+$password
$Encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($auth)
$EncodedPassword = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Encoded)
$latestArtifactURL = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $EncodedPassword"} -MaximumRedirection 0
$redirectedMessage = "$latestArtifactURL".IndexOf('http:')
$targetURL = "$latestArtifactURL".SubString("$redirectedMessage") 
Invoke-WebRequest $targetURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $EncodedPassword"} -OutFile "MyApp.zip"
```